# How to calculate daylight saving switchover dates for EU?

Tags: c, dst

Given a UTC timestamp, I'd like to determine if DST was active at that time in European Union.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of answering this question makes use of the comprehensive [tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), which is built into most operating systems, with the exception of Windows, which uses its own, similar database.

A database like this is necessary in order for the C library `localtime` and `mktime` functions to work correctly.

If you already have a broken-down date and time (year/month/day, hour:minute:second), the function you want is `mktime`.  Let's try two dates, July 8th and December 13th.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm1, tm2;
    /* July 8th */
    tm1.tm_year = 2022 - 1900;
    tm1.tm_mon = 7 - 1;
    tm1.tm_mday = 8;
    tm1.tm_hour = 12;
    tm1.tm_min = tm1.tm_sec = 0;
    tm1.tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(&tm1);
    printf("at %d:%02d:%02d on %d-%02d-%02d, DST %s in effect\n",
        tm1.tm_hour, tm1.tm_min, tm1.tm_sec,
        tm1.tm_year+1900, tm1.tm_mon+1, tm1.tm_mday,
        tm1.tm_isdst ? "was" : "was not");

    /* December 13th */
    tm2.tm_year = 2022 - 1900;
    tm2.tm_mon = 12 - 1;
    tm2.tm_mday = 13;
    tm2.tm_hour = 12;
    tm2.tm_min = tm2.tm_sec = 0;
    tm2.tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(&tm2);
    printf("at %d:%02d:%02d on %d-%02d-%02d, DST %s in effect\n",
        tm2.tm_hour, tm2.tm_min, tm2.tm_sec,
        tm2.tm_year+1900, tm2.tm_mon+1, tm2.tm_mday,
        tm2.tm_isdst ? "was" : "was not");
}
```

For me this prints

```
at 12:00:00 on 2022-07-08, DST was in effect
at 12:00:00 on 2022-12-13, DST was not in effect
```

When filling in `struct tm`, there are a couple of things to be careful of, as illustrated in the code above:

- field `tm_year` is offset by 1900
- field `tm_mon` is offset by 1 (it's 0-based)
- field `tm_isdst` contains 1 if DST is in effect, 0 if its not, or -1 if we're not sure.

So the strategy is simply: fill in a `struct tm` with the desired date/time, set `tm_isdst` to -1 indicating that we don't know whether DST is in effect or not, and call `mktime`.  Among other things, `mktime` figures out whether DST was in effect or not, and adjusts `tm_isdst` in the pointed-to `struct tm` accordingly.

If the "UTC timestamp" you said you had to start with is a Unix-style `time_t` value, you can answer your question using the `localtime` function, which starts with a `time_t` value and constructs a `struct tm`:

```
time_t t = 1670714400;
struct tm *tmp = localtime(&t);
printf("at %d:%02d:%02d on %d-%02d-%02d, DST %s in effect\n",
    tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec,
    tmp->tm_year+1900, tmp->tm_mon+1, tmp->tm_mday,
    tmp->tm_isdst ? "was" : "was not");
```

On my machine this prints

```
at 18:20:00 on 2022-12-10, DST was not in effect
```

I've glossed over one important question, which is: how do `localtime` and `mktime` know which of the world's time zone and daylight savings rules to use?  For Unix-like operating systems, at least, it's based on an environment variable, `TZ`.  Normally it's set to match the part of the world where you are (where your computer is installed), although you can set it to anything you want.  For example, if I wanted my program to use the rules for Central European time, I'd set TZ to `Europe/Rome`, the tz identifier for that zone.

The usual way of setting environment variables (again, under Unix) is from the shell, outside of your C program.  For example, to run my program under a different time zone, I might type

```
TZ=Europe/Rome
export TZ
./myprogram
```

Or there's this shortcut:

```
TZ=Europe/Rome ./myprogram
```

Or, you can also set an environment variable from within a C program, like this:

```
setenv("TZ", "Europe/Rome", 1);
tzset();
```

`setenv` is a Posix function, not Standard C.  After you change the `TZ` environment variable from within a C program like this, you have to call `tzset` to let the timezone-related functions like `mktime` know you've done so.

Comment: UTC ignores leap seconds, so that will lead to errors; tz db can change so that can lead to errors; european union did not always exist so that leads to problems

Answer (score 0):

Daylight saving time is observed from the last Sunday in March (02:00 CET) to the last Sunday in October (03:00 CEST). (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe). To test, compare e.g. with https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany?year=2022

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//included for reference only
int wd(int y, int m, int d)
{
    return (d += m<3?y--:y-2, 23*m/9 + d+4 + y/4 - y/100 + y/400) % 7;
    //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Keith
}

#define GregorianAdpotion 1752
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int y = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 2022;
    if (y <= GregorianAdpotion)
        return 1;
    //https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_last_Sunday_of_each_month#FreeBASIC
    int x = 33+y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400; //common part of Keith for Mar and Oct
    int last_Sun_March = 31 - x % 7;
    int last_Sun_Oct = 31 - (4 + x) % 7;
    printf("DST from %d-03-%d 02:00 CET ", y, last_Sun_March);
    printf("to %d-10-%d 03:00 CEST\n", y, last_Sun_Oct);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that [struct tm](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) includes `tm_isdst`.