# How to get the current time in a different city in C?

Tags: c, time, timezone, localtime, time.h

I'm writing a server in C that is meant to get a request over UDP for the time in either:
Doha, Prague, New York or Berlin.
How can I produce the right response?

I  tried looking into the localtime() method but couldn't find anything relating to a timezone

Comment: you can check [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/LC_categories)

Comment: This looks like it's only taking care of the formatting, not the actual timezone.
Are you sure this'll work?

Comment: "New York" is not a _capital city_.  It is a major city in its time zone.

Comment: True!
I'll change the question to city

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out on my own.
Let's say I want the current time in Doha.
Apparently Doha's time is UTC+3.
Which means that I need to get the current UTC time and add 3 hours to it like so:

```
char* response = malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
time_t now = time(NULL);
tm* t = gmtime(&now); //Gets me the UTC time
t->tm_hour += 3; //Adds 3 hours to it
mktime(t); //Normalizes it (so it's 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour and so on...)
strftime(response, 255, "%H:%M:%S", t);
```

Comment: Does this work when tm_hour is 23?

Comment: Only if you use mktime on it.
It'll normalize it.

Comment: What is `new` in this C question?

Comment: er, you need to handle DST, and that is set by psusdo-random government decree

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll edit new to malloc

Comment: In the case of DST, I suppose you can do t->tm_isdst = 1 and mktime(t) will change it accordingly but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EladMoshe That's `tm_isdst = -1`, not 1.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74756775).

Comment: Careful with assumptions about fixed offsets.  That's what the TZDB is for.  Watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: Even Doha wasn't always UTC+3.  It used to be UTC+4.  The switch happened in 1972.  See the chart on https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/qatar/doha?syear=1960&eyear=2030 or the source data in the tzdb here: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/b2e7a66b74c5b7a94c91d3e9f131b02199c9dd0b/asia#L3520-L3525